# Why TravisCI builds fails during npm install due to file lock

Tags: npm, travis-ci

`npm install` fails due to a file lock issue. How can I avoid this?

[Here is the log of travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/wordnik/swagger-editor#L78):

```
npm ERR! EEXIST, open '/home/travis/.npm/83f1dfb7-vis-npm-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: /home/travis/.npm/83f1dfb7-vis-npm-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again. 
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab090.5
npm ERR! command "/home/travis/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/node" "/home/travis/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/travis/build/wordnik/swagger-editor
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /home/travis/.npm/83f1dfb7-vis-npm-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! not ok code 0
The command "npm install" failed and exited with 47 during .
```

Answer (score 12):

Updating to npm to version 2 fixed my issue.

```
install:
  - npm install -g npm@2
```

Comment: Not sure why this is still a problem, but it fixed my issue, thank you.